# Phrasing $\lim_{n \to \infty}A^n v = w \implies Aw=w$ as a consequence of Banach's Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I'd like to know if there's a nice way to obtain this result from the Banach Fixed Point Theorem:

> Let $A$ be a (stochastic*) matrix and $v$ a vector such that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}A^nv = w.$$
>
> Then $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue 1.

I've produced a proof of this another way but I think the Banach theorem could make it cleaner. How does the following sketch look?

Let $|\cdot|$ be a norm on the vector space which induces a matrix norm on $A$. Let $d$ be the standard metric w.r.t. this norm; then since A is stochastic

$$d(Av,Aw) = |Av - Aw| \leq |A||v-w| \leq |v-w| = d(v,w).$$

Unfortunately since $|A|$ = 1, it's not quite a contraction mapping. Is there still somewhere we can go with this line of thinking?

*Feel free to weaken this condition if possible.

**If someone has a better title go ahead and change it.

Comment: I don't think the Banach fixed point theorem would work (unless you apply it in a way I'm not thinking of).  The consequence of this theorem is that there is a *unique* fixed point, while any vector in $\text{span}\{w\}$ will be a fixed point of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

I think any application of the Banach theorem here is overkill.  Here's a nice proof of the desired result:

We are given the existence of the limit $w = \lim_{n \to \infty}A^n v$. The mapping $v \mapsto Av$ is continuous (since $A$ is a matrix, i.e. a linear map between finite dimensional normed vector spaces).  It follows that
$$
Aw = A \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}A^n v \right) = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}A(A^n v) = \lim_{n \to \infty}A^{n+1} v =
\lim_{n \to \infty}A^{n} v = w
$$